# Python MYSQL-connector backup creation

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

**Current Problemset**:

- Python application including mysql_connector object
- Remote Server only accessible using mysql (no ssh, rsh, telnet, etc.)

**Target**:

- Use mysql connector to create a database backup to file (either on the local machine or a network place - e.g. Samba Share)
- I want to avoid collecting each row from each table and dump single rows into ascii files.

**Environment**:

- Operating systems: *Windows, Linux*
- Python Version:    *2.7*

***What i tried so far***:

- Checked the [API Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-reference.html) and [Extension API Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-cext-reference.html)
- **EDIT:** I also searched [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) using keywords *mysql-connector* and *backup* as well as *copy table*

Any help and hints are welcome!

Comment: Could you use mysql-dump? Or you NEED to run it in python?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comment. I cannot use mysql-dump as this would require server side access. The application is a client and therefore relies on the python methods only

Comment: mysqldump is a client too, you don't have to run it on the server. You only need the host, username and password.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu based linux distro run the following commands to get a full backup(including schema) of database named my_database.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
mysqldump -h<your_db_server> -u <your_user> -p<your_password> -e --databases my_database > my_backup.sql
```

You only have to run this on the server if your local machine has no access to the db, but you said you have mysql access to the server, so this should work fine. Remember not to add a space between your password and the -p. (If password is passwd, write `-ppasswd`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using mysqldump - it means i have to install that on the client machine, but it's more reliable (for me) than a complex script that selects every row from every table.

```
try:
    mysqldump_process = run(["/usr/bin/mysqldump","-h",host_endpoint,"-P","3306","-u","admin",master_user_password,"--result-file=/tmp/sanitised_dump.sql","--databases",schema_name], capture_output=True, check=True, text=True)
    print ("mysqldumping")

    print ("Process: ", mysqldump_process)
    print ("Command output: ", mysqldump_process.stdout)
except:
    print("mysqldump failed (but i don't know how to get the output in the exception handler)")
    print ("Process: ", mysqldump_process)
```